# How to create a year column in monetdb to automatically be set with the current time

Tags: monetdb

I want to create a table with default value set to the current year

```
CREATE TABLE Date
(
 "year" smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT extract(year from current_time)
);
```

It throws an error:

```
!42000!syntax error, unexpected YEAR in: "select year"
```

The same command if I run using mclient it works fine.

```
sql>select extract(year from current_date);
+---------------------+
| second_current_date |
+=====================+
|              2015 |
+---------------------+
1 tuple (0.130ms)
sql>

sql>select "year"(NOW());
+-------------------+
| current_timestamp |
+===================+
|              2015 |
+-------------------+
1 tuple (0.380ms)
```

I only want the year. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are attempting to extract 'year' from CURRENT_**TIME** when you should be attempting to get it from CURRENT_**DATE**

Try:

```
CREATE TABLE Date
(
     "year" smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT extract(year from current_date)
);
```

Comment: Still No luck, I get the same error:`!42000!syntax error, unexpected YEAR in: "select year"`